# Clear a HashMap after adding to a List, in Java

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I would be very grateful if you could help me with the following Java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class JavaApplication2 {
    static ArrayList<HashMap> list_test = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    static HashMap<String,String> test =new HashMap<>();
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test.put("name", "jhon");
        test.put("lastname", "mckoy");
        list_test.add(test);
        test.clear();
        System.out.println(list_test);
        test.put("name", "Tom");
        test.put("lastname", "Red");
        list_test.add(test);
        
    }
    
}
```

I have two variables one called list_test (ArrayList ) and another called test (HashMap <String, String>). My goal is to make a ArrayList of HashMap  using the following code, but after executing: `test.clear ();` then the content of list_test is deleted. Why?
Is there another way to make a HashMap list? Which?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value: basically, when you add `test` to `list_test`, you aren't actually adding the value of the HashMap to the list; you're only adding in a reference to `test`. So, when you clear `test` and try to get the element from the list, it checks `test` and sees that it's empty.

Comment: Building on that, if you wanted to make a list full of hashmap's all you would have to do is change list_test.add(test) to list_test.add(test.copy()). That way everytime you are adding a hashmap into the array it's a copy of the original one not the original one itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

With your code, the same map object that you put in the list is the same map object that you clear. Instead, add a ***copy* of your map** into your list.

```
listOfMapsOfNames.add( Map.copyOf( mapOfNames ) );  // Make an unmodifiable copy of map to be added to list.
```

## Make a copy of your map

Apparently you want a *copy* of your map added to the list.

Your code puts the original map into the list. So now you have two references to the same map: (a) the variable `test` points to the map, and (b) the first element in the list named `list_test` points to the very same map object. If you use either reference to change the map's contents, both references see that change, given that they **both point to the same object**.

Either:

- Call [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) to make an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) copy of the map. Ex: `Map.copyOf( oldMap )`
- Pass the map to the constructor of another `Map` implementation to copy the entries over to a new modifiable map. Ex: `new HashMap<>( oldMap )`.

You should consider making a habit of using the more general superclass or interface rather than concrete class in your references, where practical. So `List<Map> list_test` rather than `ArrayList<HashMap> list_test`.

You should parameterize the parameterization of your `List`. So `List< Map< String, String > >` rather than `List< Map >`.

Using more descriptive names on your Java identifiers will make your code easier to read and debug. So something like `listOfMapsOfNames` rather than `list_test`.

### Example code

Here is some example code.

I dropped the `static` on the map and list as that is irrelevant.

Notice the two calls `Map.copyOf( mapOfNames )`.

```java
List< Map< String, String > > listOfMapsOfNames = new ArrayList<>() ;
Map< String, String > mapOfNames = new HashMap<>() ;

mapOfNames.put( "name", "John" );
mapOfNames.put( "lastname", "McKoy" );
listOfMapsOfNames.add( Map.copyOf( mapOfNames ) );  // Make an unmodifiable copy of map to be added to list.

System.out.println( "map before clear: " + mapOfNames );
mapOfNames.clear();
System.out.println( "map after clear: " + mapOfNames );

mapOfNames.put( "name", "Tom" );
mapOfNames.put( "lastname" , "Red" );
listOfMapsOfNames.add( Map.copyOf( mapOfNames ) );  // Make an unmodifiable copy of map to be added to list.

System.out.println( "map after 2nd add: " + mapOfNames );
System.out.println( "list at the end: " + listOfMapsOfNames );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mhUsR2).

```
map before clear: {name=John, lastname=McKoy}
map after clear: {}
map after 2nd add: {name=Tom, lastname=Red}
list at the end: [{lastname=McKoy, name=John}, {lastname=Red, name=Tom}]
```

---

## `record`

Not relevant to your Question, but for your information, the use of a class might make more sense than using a `Map` for tracking first name and last name. And now we have an easier way to write such a class: *records*.

The [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature is new in [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16). A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Bonus: A record can be declared locally as well as being declared nested or separate.

Notice the following version of your code becomes more expressive (and shorter) with `record`.

```java
record Person(String firstName , String lastName) {}
List < Person > people = new ArrayList <>();

people.add( new Person( "John" , "McKoy" ) );
people.add( new Person( "Tom" , "Red" ) );
```

> people.toString(): [Person[firstName=John, lastName=McKoy], Person[firstName=Tom, lastName=Red]]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. clone of 'test' (HashMap<String,String>)
2. create new Map from 'test' (HashMap<String,String>)

Here is the code:

```
public class ListOfMapJavaApplication2 {
    static ArrayList<HashMap> list_test = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    static HashMap<String,String> test =new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    test.put("name", "jhon");
    test.put("lastname", "mckoy");
    //list_test.add(new HashMap<String,String>(test));
    list_test.add((HashMap<String,String>)test.clone());
    test.clear();
    System.out.println(list_test);
    test.put("name", "Tom");
    test.put("lastname", "Red");
    //list_test.add(new HashMap<String,String>(test));
    list_test.add((HashMap<String,String>)test.clone());

    }
}
```

Comment: [Dr. Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch), the author of the `Map` and `List` classes, [advises against using `clone`](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is happing because of call by reference you can take new reference using the new keyword.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main
{
static ArrayList<HashMap> list_test = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    static HashMap<String,String> test =new HashMap<>();
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test.put("name", "jhon");
        test.put("lastname", "mckoy");
        list_test.add(test);
        test = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(list_test);
        test.put("name", "Tom");
        test.put("lastname", "Red");
        list_test.add(test);
        System.out.println(list_test);
    }
}
```